# SQL Select Max Count Nested?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, where-clause

```
SELECT N.National_PosID, N.Title, C.First_Name, C.Mid_Name, C.Last_Name, count(*)  
FROM National_Position N, Candidate C, Vote V
WHERE N.National_PosID = C.National_PosID AND V.Candidate_ID = C.Candidate_ID
Group by N.National_PosID, N.Title, C.First_Name, C.Mid_Name, C.Last_Name;
```

The output

```
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Title      | First_Name | Mid_Name | Last_Name | count(*) |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Agueda     | Sarahann   |          | MCMAHON   |      557 |
| Amesha     | Maurice    |          | GREEN     |     1071 |
| Kiante     | Jesicca    |          | WINTERS   |      482 |
| Kieffer    | Serene     |          | HIGGINS   |     1285 |
| Koray      | Ahley      |          | COLLIER   |     1287 |
| SENATE     | Daisy      | Hao      | MADDOX    |     1316 |
| SENATE     | Radhames   | Jakson   | MURILLO   |     1269 |
| SENATE     | Rayan      | Kaitlynn | FRYE      |     1089 |
| SENATE     | Rio        | Krysti   | HUGHES    |      457 |
| SENATE     | Shalondra  | Nila     | HORTON    |      551 |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
10 rows in set (1.33 sec)
```

The problem is that how do I get the output of the only the max count only. Only outputting the max votes row. This is run on mysql.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question: oracle, sql-server, mysql, ...?

Comment: And what is your expected result? Just one, record that has the maximum count (here: Daisy Maddox)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subquery` to get the `max` `count` of your original result.

```
SELECT t1.National_PosID, t1.Title, t1.First_Name, t1.Mid_Name, t1.Last_Name, max(ct)
FROM(
    SELECT N.National_PosID, N.Title, C.First_Name, C.Mid_Name, C.Last_Name, count(*) ct 
    FROM National_Position N
    INNER JOIN Candidate C ON N.National_PosID = C.National_PosID
    INNER JOIN Vote V ON V.Candidate_ID = C.Candidate_ID  
    INNER JOIN      
    GROUP BY N.National_PosID, N.Title, C.First_Name, C.Mid_Name, C.Last_Name) as t1
GROUP BY t1.National_PosID, t1.Title, t1.First_Name, t1.Mid_Name, t1.Last_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle (the way you display the results of your query suggests that), then you can use the `FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY` syntax to exhibit only the record that has the maximum count. This syntax is available since Oracle 12.1.

```
SELECT 
    N.National_PosID, 
    N.Title, 
    C.First_Name, 
    C.Mid_Name, 
    C.Last_Name, count(*) cnt
FROM 
    National_Position N
    INNER JOIN Candidate C ON N.National_PosID = C.National_PosID
    INNER JOIN Vote V ON V.Candidate_ID = C.Candidate_ID
GROUP BY 
    N.National_PosID, 
    N.Title, 
    C.First_Name, 
    C.Mid_Name, 
    C.Last_Name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

In Mysql (and Postgres), just replace `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` with `LIMIT 1`.

Note: implicit joins have fallen out of favor *long* ago. Always use explicit joins. I have modified your query accordingly.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        N.National_PosID, 
        N.Title, 
        C.First_Name, 
        C.Mid_Name, 
        C.Last_Name, count(*) cnt
    FROM 
        National_Position N
        INNER JOIN Candidate C ON N.National_PosID = C.National_PosID
        INNER JOIN Vote V ON V.Candidate_ID = C.Candidate_ID
    GROUP BY 
        N.National_PosID, 
        N.Title, 
        C.First_Name, 
        C.Mid_Name, 
        C.Last_Name
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
) x 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Yes it does output the rows in descending order but do to the fact that mysql doesnt accept where rownum and fetch first 1 rows only. It does not have this function

Comment: @ShengZhang: In Mysql (and Postgres), just replace `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` with `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Yes I realized that but the limit 1 is only limiting the first row with the max count, but there is a difference in each position since the national is separated into president and senate position and so need the max count of two position.

Comment: @ShengZhang: ok now I think I see what you want. That would have been easier if you had provided your expected results in the first place, as I initially commented. Can you please tell me which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: The version is 5.1